# ImproperlyConfigured ENGINE sqlite , Django

Tags: django, django-settings

http://pastebin.com/umBiCJvp here's the traceback and settings. I'm using Django version 1.2.3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are running Django 1.2.3. This error message is common when changing to Django 1.2 from 1.1 (since the way database settings are defined has changed).

You can check your version of Django by running `python manage.py shell` and then:

```
import django
print django.VERSION
```

That should give you `(1,2,3,'final',0)` or something similar. If it's not 1.2.x then thats your problem.

Comment: >>> print django.VERSION
(1, 2, 3, 'final', 0). Seems like it's something else.

Comment: Nevermind, problem solved. I used the exact same database settings in other project and it worked, it probably was something with my old code.